# Unable to launch "gnome-session --session=ubuntu" X session

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, desktop

Every time I get into my Linux VM (10.4, no choice in version, I know it is end of life), I get an error:

```
: unable to launch "gnome-session --session=ubuntu" X session ---
"gnome-session --session=ubuntu" not found; falling back to default session.
```

I press OK, and it loads. But I would like to have it work right...

I found from another question that I can change the default session by following this:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM#Change_the_Default_Session

> Changing the Default Session
>
> The default session is set by
>   configuration in /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/ that session
>   packages provide. If you need to override this you can set:
>
> [SeatDefaults]
>
> user-session=name Where name is the name of the session
>
> .desktop file from /usr/share/xsessions/*.desktop.

But... `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/` doesn't exist. The only folder in `/usr/share/lightdm/` is `remote-sessions`.

Also, `/usr/share/xsessions/*.desktop` doesn't exist... There are two files `Ubuntu` and `Gnome`...

Are those files the desktop-type files? How would I place them in the `lightdm.conf.d`?

Answer (score 4):

this answer from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382068/failed-to-load-session-gnome-after-system-crash) did the trick for me.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Do not restart. This could effectively leave your system without GUI.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This will install all the missing GNOME dependencies.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked. Kudos

Comment: what if system is already rebooted because i get this error on login screen. so any idea how to force ubuntu too boot in cli

Comment: This worked for me too, thank you. Maybe mark this as the accepted answer? NOTE: there are LOTS of GNOME dependencies because the re-install took me about 10 minutes.