# Unable to launch "cinnamon-session-cinnamon"

Tags: linux, terminal, linux-mint

I just tried to boot Linux (I am using Mint), I got the following error:

```
: unable to launch "cinnamon-session-cinnamon" X session ---
"cinnamon-session-cinnamon" not found; falling back to default session.
```

Normally when I would login in, there would be a little mountain logo thing in the top right corner of the little login box, as seen in this picture: [image: example of Linux Mint login screen] But now when it is giving me that error, when I login, there is no logo in the corner... which is a little odd.

---

When I started composing this question, it suggested [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/813170/unable-to-launch-gnome-session-session-ubuntu-x-session)

The only problem with that question/answer is that when I click "okay" it doesn't load anything (or at least that what it looks like). I can press `ctrl`+`alt`+`leftArrow` or `ctrl`+`alt`+`rightArrow` and I see the little window to switch workspaces, but that is about it... I can't tell if the terminal opens up when I press `ctrl`+`alt`+`T`. I tried doing the `shutdown` command to see if the terminal was open and I could give commands, but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From your description I think `cinnamon` package is not installed or `cinnamon-session-cinnamon` command deleted/removed.

Try this steps:

- Press CTRL-ALT-F1 to change to text mode and login with your user.
- Change user to root with su or sudo command.
- Check package and program:

  - Query Cinnamon packge is installed or not: `dpkg -l cinnamon`

    - If there is no reuslt, the package is not installed or deleted/removed, install package: `apt install cinnamon`
  - If package installed (there is result `dpkg` command), list command: `ls -l /usr/bin/cinnamon-session-cinnamon`

    - If there is no reuslt, the package is deleted/removed, reinstall it: `apt reinstall cinnamon`
- If there are results both of them commands check `ls` output again, you should see permissions like this: `-rwxr-xr-x`

  - If your permission is different, set it: `chmod 755 /usr/bin/cinnamon-session-cinnamon`
- Reboot your computer.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you _so_ much! This did help me a lot... though there is one thing that you should add/change. When I did the `apt reinstall cinnamon` command it said that cinnamon would not reinstall because it wasn't currently installed.So I just did `apt install cinnamon` and it worked. So you should say something like "If it tells you that cinnamon isn't installed so it won't reinstall, do this command: `apt install cinnamon`.

Comment: @JacobHornbeck, thanks the feedback. I reorganized the steps and added your comment.